# how to stop executing getview method of customlistview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to stop the executing of getview() method every time while scrolling list view.While scrolling list view the list view is refreshed , but i don't want to refresh it.How i can do?
Please can any one help me?
Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The ListView calls `getView()` each time it needs to generate a row to be shown. Rows are recycled in a ListView to conserve memory, therefore when scrolling you will se many calls to `getView()`.

Please, [watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) to understand the essentials of ListView and how to improve the performance of `getView()`.